# Error in office app upload in office365 office app

Tags: upload, desktop, onedrive, office365, office-app

I developed an office app.
I want to upload that office app in office365(sky drive).

But i'm getting an error

> App Warning This app is not available in the Web App. Open this document in desktop version of Office to use the app.

What should be the possible issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify how are you trying to upload the app through SkyDrive? Are you adding it as a file to a library? How did you develop the app? Have you used NAPA?

If it's an App for internal use only, have you tried uploading in Sharepoint Admin Centre>Apps>List of applications (first link)

If you are trying to publish to internet you should use Seller Dashboard.